# Is it possible to combine two pooledMap arrays in deno?

Tags: deno

```
const pool = pooledMap(20, feeds, (url) => {
  return getWithXidel(url, '//item/link');
});
const pool2 = pooledMap(20, feedEntries, (url) => {
  return getWithXidel(url, "//entry/link[@rel='alternate']/@href");
});
```

```
for await (const data of pool) {
  console.log('data: ', data); 
  console.log('found links: ', data?.links?.length);

  for (const link of data?.links) {
    const url = link.trim();

    results.push(url);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to combine these two pools into one? I tried Array.concat but it breaks it. says its not iterable.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

[Deno standard library](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std)'s [`pooledMap`](https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std@0.116.0/async/mod.ts#pooledMap) returns an `AsyncIterableIterator` that, like an `AsyncGenerator`, can be iterated through using [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) and is not *synchronously* iterable.

Deno standard library also provides a [`MuxAsyncIterator`](https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std@0.116.0/async/mod.ts#MuxAsyncIterator) that "multiplexes multiple async iterators into a single stream" which you can use to "combine" multiple pools:

```ts
import {
  pooledMap,
  MuxAsyncIterator,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.116.0/async/mod.ts";

const pool = pooledMap(20, feeds, (url) => {
  return getWithXidel(url, '//item/link');
});
const pool2 = pooledMap(20, feedEntries, (url) => {
  return getWithXidel(url, "//entry/link[@rel='alternate']/@href");
});

const mux = new MuxAsyncIterator();
mux.add(pool);
mux.add(pool2);

for await (const data of mux) {
  console.log('data: ', data); 
  console.log('found links: ', data?.links?.length);

  for (const link of data?.links) {
    const url = link.trim();

    results.push(url);
  }
}
```